# why element is visible while using opacity : 1 but it is out of window?

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have set of div's . All are out of window as I gave `negative value of left`.

My issue is when I change the opacity of any div to 1 . it is visible on window why ? . or it other words why it is visible at position `left:0` as it is present out of window ?

example code

```
<div class="crystal-slider__slide" data-crystal-slide="2" style="width: 25%; transition: opacity 500ms ease-out 0s; left: -25%; opacity: 1; z-index: 97;">
        2

      </div>
```

here is above div I gave `left:-25%` which is out of window. but when I give opacity one it come in widow or display the contend why ?

here is my code

https://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/RwVEgrJ

Comment: You need to use `position: absolute` instead of relative. Then your `left:-25%` will work properly.

Comment: I think it's the float left that's confusing the issue, but the above may be right

Comment: @why position absolute doing this ?

Comment: If you want to stack your `slider` div then it's ok to apply relative. But in your case, your slider divs should overlap on each other. And in that case you need to use `position:absolute`. In `position:relative` elements are placed to their original position.

Comment: you can also increase the amount it is off the screen to 50% then it properly gets hidden even in relative. I think when there is more than one element positioned relatively they go in a row IDK. The opacity is just confusing the issue if it is set to 0 you can't see the element at one you can but either way the left isn't working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is not out of the window because it has position: relative set by:

```
.crystal-slider__slide {
  ...
  position: relative;
}
```

This means its ultimate position is immediately after the element before (so 2 would show on the line immediately after 1) but you then set `left: -25%` so it goes back on the line to overwrite its previous sibling.

If you remove that position: relative; then the element with content 2 does go back by 25% of the parent element width.

It can be useful in these circumstances to see exactly where an element is positioned by using your browser's inspect facility in its dev tools and look at computed values as well as exactly who is setting what styles.